# vscode python venv - activate.ps1 is used instead of activate.bat

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-venv

In the vscode user settings "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Command Prompt" is declared.
I have created a python virtual env (venv) from within vscode.
When opening vscode from within the venv, an integrated cmd-terminal is opened. The command "& /.venv/Scripts/Activate.ps1" is automatically executed leading to the error ""&" kann syntaktisch an dieser Stelle nicht verarbeitet werden."

I would have awaited, that, due to the global cmd-shell setting, the automatically executed script would be "/.venv/Scripts/activate.bat". Executing this script manually in the integrated terminal leads to the correct activation of the environment.
I have tried what I have found in the documentation concerning terminal profiles but didn't manage to get the initial integrated terminal to execute the right script.
Could someone please give me a hint to the necessary configuration variable(s).

Comment: The problem is not, that the initially executed command is not found, but that the wrong command (the one for powershell instead of the one for cmd) is executed.

Comment: What is your setting for `terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows`? I think setting that to `PowerShell` will fix your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you choose a virtual environment interpreter, vscode will automatically activate the environment when you build a new terminal.

```
    "python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true,
```

Your problem may be caused by the terminal cache, add the following setting to turn off recording terminal session history

```
    "terminal.integrated.enablePersistentSessions": false,
```

Comment: After adding both options to the settings.json of the venv the terminal was opened executing activate.bat as awaited.

Comment: @JialeDu this doesn't work for me. Could you please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78005138/make-venv-default-terminal-for-project-in-vscode